# How to use LIKE with ANY in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to use the LIKE ANY operator to exclude rows based on an array of substrings, but BigQuery does not recognize it.

```
     
        declare unlaunched_clistings array<string>;

        set unlaunched_clistings = {unlaunched_clistings} ;

        select * from {p}.simeon_logs.process_errors e
        where not e.message like any(unlaunched_clistings)
```

Error :  LIKE ANY is not supported at [8:32]

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIKE ANY is not supported, however you can use following 2 ways:

1. Use LIKE with ORs between them

   ```
   WITH table AS (
     SELECT 'abc' as col union all 
     SELECT 'xzy' as col

   )

   SELECT col
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE (col like '%abc%'
   OR col like '%cde%' OR col like '%something%')
   ```
2. User RegEx

   ```
   WITH table AS (
   SELECT 'abc' as col 
   UNION ALL  
   SELECT 'xzy' as col

   )

   SELECT col
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(col
     , 'abc|cde|something')
   ```

Above both will give you abc row.